# having trouble uploading datatable to SqlServer 2008 from Winforms application

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, ado.net

I'm streaming data from a CSV file and trying to import it to SQL Server 2008. I've looked around on the web and I've come up with this approach , which is not working. Any ideas on how to make it better (in the sense that it actually works).

The input parameter is the CSV data in a DataTable.

Here's the code:

```
   private void ExportCSV(DataTable dtCSV)
     {
        DateTime dayOfYear = DateTime.Now.Date;
        dtCSV.TableName = "ActivationDate_"+dayOfYear.ToString();
        string createTempTable = "SELECT * INTO ThisActivation FROM @tvp";
        using (SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(createTempTable,GetConnection()))
        {
            adap.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@tvp", SqlDbType.NVarChar, int.MaxValue);
            adap.InsertCommand.Parameters["@tvp"].Value = dtCSV;
            adap.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please be more specific that "[it's] not working". See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't parameterize table names (or column names, for that matter).

One option it to revert to [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html), though that opens you up to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

This will work, though you should be very careful to validate `dtCSV` to avoid SQL injection.

```
string createTempTable = "SELECT * INTO ThisActivation FROM " + dtCSV;
```

Comment: okay... how should I be doing this then? A link to code-samples will be much appreciated but I have googled and it's not been much use, the question is too broad to get any useful info without trawling through scores of pages

Comment: @Dani - the article I linked to (dynamic SQL) is comprehensive.

Comment: @Dani - no problem. I edited my original post and added the links later on... always refresh before commenting ;)

Comment: should I still use the the SqlDataAdapter or will a SqlCommand do the job?